# Display percentage in Jquery progressbar

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a progress bar updated dynamically in my page, I would like to dislay the percentage in middle of it, but I cannot figure out how. This is my progress bar on my page:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active"> 
   <div id="prog" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
      <span id="progress-value"></span>
   </div> 
</div>
```

This is my jQuery code that Updates the progress bar:

```
$.ajax({    
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var pct = evt.loaded / evt.total;

                $("#prog").css({ width: pct * 100 + '%' });
                $('#progress-value').html(pct * 100);

            }
        }, false);

        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var pct = evt.loaded / evt.total;

                $("#prog").css({ width: pct * 100 + '%' });
                $('#progress-value').html(pct*100);
                if (pct === 1) {
                    $('#prog').addClass('hide');
                }
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
```

Ity updates the progress bar, as I see it progressing during data loading, but it doesn't display the percentage. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $('#prog').removeClass('hide'); At the start of xhr?

Comment: Yes, I have several buttons, everyone of them calling an ajax request, and at the end of the loading I hide the progress bar to display data. When I call a button I remove the Hide class because I want to display the progressbar again, and it works

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is utilize the `data-` attribute on elements (in this case I'll use `data-progress`), and also the `content:` property for that element in CSS.

For example the JQuery:

```
$.ajax({    
xhr: function () {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var pct = evt.loaded / evt.total;

            $("#prog").css({ width: pct * 100 + '%' })
                      .attr('data-progress', pct * 100 + '%');

        }
    }, false);

    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var pct = evt.loaded / evt.total;

            $("#prog").css({ width: pct * 100 + '%' })
                      .attr('data-progress', pct * 100 + '%');
            if (pct === 1) {
                $('#prog').addClass('hide');
            }
        }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
},
```

So in the code, you will see that while it updates the physical width on the progress bar, it also updates the data attribute at the same time. Naturally, the CSS will auto update with the new value.

And in the CSS, it would be:

```
#prog[data-progress] {
    position: relative;
}
#prog[data-progress]:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: attr(data-progress);
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* this sets the text to be exactly in the middle of the parent element */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it still doesn't display the percentage

Comment: Have you checked the developer console if the :before pseudo element is appearing? Have you tried playing around with the z-index of the progress bar and the pseudo element?

Comment: Yes, it creates the :before element, I tried to assign a great value of z-index to the span element, but the text in the span still isn't visible.

Comment: This solution was to replace the need of the `<span id="progress-value">` tag. Remove that from the HTML page, as the `:before` pseudo element replaces the need for the span tag.

Comment: Ok I solved, in the Chrome Developer tools I noticed that the .progress class adds a `text-indent: -9999px;` property, so it was for that reason that it didn't display percentage. I added a   `text-indent: initial;` style attribute in my `<div id="prog">`,. I update the percentage with `$("#prog").css({ width: pct * 100 + '%' }).text(pct * 100 + '%');` and it displays the percentage value