# How to get Ajax Progress Events in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, progress-bar

I have a file to import contacts, I want to get the progress while progressing data on server side,

Sample image is attached,

[image]

my existing jquery code is,

```
    $(".general_form2").each(function(){
    $(this).validate(
        {
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var form1 = document.getElementById(id);

                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: form.action,
                        type: form.method,
                        data: new FormData(form1),
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        dataType: 'html',
                        beforeSend: function () {

                        },
                        complete: function () {

                        },
                        success: function (response) {

                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            alert("Error" + JSON.stringify(error));
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    );
});
```

How can I modify this code to get desired results?

Comment: Please note that SO isn't a "Please fix my code" service, we're a specific problem solving board instead. Try some stuff, see what you can get to. Then come back with a question that involves a specific problem with your code and we'll be glad to help you then :)

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346816/display-percentage-in-jquery-progressbar